# Flutter: restart SlideAnimation from current object position

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

I've got a `SlideAnimation` on an object that get's triggered every time I tap the screen. The object simply slides up atm but when I tap the screen again the animation starts from the original position of the object again. How would I capture the position the object ended in the last animation and perform the animation from there on?
I've got the following code for the creating of the SlideTransition:

```
        new SlideTransition(
          child: new Container(
            child: char,
          ),
          position: _characterPosition,
        )
```

And this code for the actual animation:

```
_characterPosition = new FractionalOffsetTween(
  begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
  end: const FractionalOffset(0.0, -0.2),
).animate(new CurvedAnimation(
  parent: _characterAnimationController,
  curve: Curves.easeOut,
  )
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the simplest case you can use your `_characterAnimationController`. [AnimationController](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController-class.html) has two related methods [stop](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController/stop.html) and [forward](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/animation/AnimationController/forward.html). Verify current animation's state and invoke required method:

```
void _onTap() {
    if (_characterAnimationController.isAnimating) {
      _characterAnimationController.stop(canceled: false);
    } else {
      _characterAnimationController.forward();
    }
}
```

To extend animation after completion you can reset `_characterAnimationController` state via `value`(or create new one) and update position. Complete example:

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  Animation _characterPosition;
  AnimationController _characterAnimationController;
  FractionalOffset _beginOffset;
  FractionalOffset _endOffset;
  FractionalOffset _animationOffset;

  void _restartAnimation() {
    _characterAnimationController.value = 0.0;
    _beginOffset = _endOffset;
    _endOffset = _endOffset + _animationOffset;

    setState(() {
      _characterPosition = _generateCharacterPosition();
    });

    _characterAnimationController.forward();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationOffset = const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.15);
    _beginOffset = const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0);
    _endOffset = _animationOffset;

    _characterAnimationController = new AnimationController(
        duration: new Duration(seconds: 5), vsync: this);
    _characterPosition = _generateCharacterPosition();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new InkWell(
        child: new SlideTransition(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Text("Hello"),
          ),
          position: _characterPosition,
        ),
        onTap: _onTap,
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onTap() {
    if (_characterAnimationController.isAnimating) {
      _characterAnimationController.stop(canceled: false);
    } else if (_characterAnimationController.status ==
        AnimationStatus.completed) {
      _restartAnimation();
    } else {
      _characterAnimationController.forward();
    }
  }

  Animation _generateCharacterPosition() => new FractionalOffsetTween(
        begin: _beginOffset,
        end: _endOffset,
      )
          .animate(new CurvedAnimation(
        parent: _characterAnimationController,
        curve: Curves.easeOut,
      ));
}
```

Comment: This works for the when the animation is not finished yet. But once it is finished and you tap the screen again, the animation starts from the original position again. Any other ideas?

Comment: What behavior do you want after animation finishes and you tap again? Can you give some example?

Comment: Sure, probably my bad for not explaining it well enough but:
I'd like to be able to start an animation and once it stops (either because it is stopped or it finishes) I'd like to offset the object again with the animation but from the new location it just animated to.

Comment: Updated answer with simple example of "extendable" animation. Does it work for you?

Comment: That makes my character off screen unfortunately. But I think I get your approach so I'll try to build further on this and let you know!

Comment: I lied, woops. Turns out I commented something to much out when typing your solution over because it works just fine. Thanks for all the help!